# How do I deserialize the return json to c# class

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to deserialize the returned JSON to a simple POCO like I  normally would do with my integrations.  The issue I am having is that normally I would just grab an example json dump into an online converter and then use that class to handle my deserializations.  I would handle small issues as they came up.

1. Does anyone have a set of C# poco representing the classes returned by magento2?

My deserialization code:

```
 var orders = (MyProject.Magento2.Item)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.content, typeof(MyProject.Magento2.Item));
```

Where MyProject.Magento2.Item is the POCO of the returned object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the code to deserializing code.  The object schema on for the order repository call at:
http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html
Did not match what was returned.
for example the schema said the property name was baseshippingamount but what was actually returned was base_shipping_amount.   When I created my class definition from the schema on the website none of the values would map when deserializing.  Instead I took the returned object from my call and created the class definition and now it matched the value actually returned: base_shipping_amount

This was yesterday at around 3pm EST (black friday).  When I went to respond to this issue it seems the documentation was updated to the correct value.

tl;dr;
Yesterday the property base_shipping_amount was shown on the documentation as baseshippingamount but the actual end point was returning base_shipping_amount.  This prevented my object from mapping the values from the JSON string to the C# class.